Python not returning variable
I have a simple script which reads raw mass spectrometer data, groups the data together in 'sequences' based on timestamps, and then presents the user with a list of sequences to proceed with analyzing. The problem is, I'm not getting those lists returned... Here is the code:
import tkinter as tk
from import_raw import get_raw_data

def select_sequences(sequence_data):
    # Tkinter GUI
    root = tk.Tk() 
    root.title("Select Sequences")
    root.geometry("400x200")

    # Listbox for sequence selection
    listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode='multiple')  
    for item in reversed(sequence_data):
        listbox.insert(tk.END, f"Sequence {item['sequence_number']}: {item['start_time']} - {item['end_time']}")
    listbox.pack(fill="both")

    # Confirm button
    def confirm_selection():
        selected_indices   = listbox.curselection()
        selected_sequences = [sequence_data[len(sequence_data) - i - 1]['sequence_number'] for i in selected_indices]
        print("Selected Sequences:", selected_sequences) 
        root.destroy() 

        return selected_sequences

    tk.Button(root, text="Confirm selection", command=confirm_selection).pack()
    root.mainloop() 


all_data, sequence_data = get_raw_data() 
selected_sequences = select_sequences(sequence_data)
print("Selected Sequences:", selected_sequences)

Note the two print functions, one inside the confirm_selection() function and another at the end of the main script. Here's the output after selecting sequences 20 and 21:
Selected Sequences: [21, 20]
Selected Sequences: None

Why are the values not being returned by/retrieved from the function? Clearly I'm overlooking something very simple.
I am stumped. I was expecting both print functions to return identical values.

You’re returning that value from confirm_selection, not select_sequences.

Did you intend for confirm_selection to be a sub-function, defined inside of the select_sequences function?  That is legal code, but it's an odd way to do it.

There is 2 ways of solving this problem.

make selected_sequences variable a global variable
instead of returning selected_sequences variable from function confirm_selection return it from select_sequences function


It is utterly pointless to return anything from a Button's command= function - you're not the one calling that function, and Tkinter isn't going to do anything with the value, so where do you expect the value to go?  You need to store the value somewhere that will still be around after the function ends - a global or nonlocal variable, or perhaps an attribute of some object referenced by such a variable.

Your function select_sequences() does not have a return statement. So the return value is None -- that is a standard Python behavior. Hence, in the main body, the variables selected_sequences is assigned the value None and then it gets printed out.

Sorry, but I'm still confused. When I add "return selected_sequences" to select_sequences(), it returns an error that the variable isn't defined. I'm still missing something very obvious here, sorry.

Wait, you mean like
    selected_sequences = tk.Button(root, text="Confirm selection", command=confirm_selection).pack()
    root.mainloop() 
    return selected_sequences

?

I don't know anything about tkinter library. But for example, you create a variable in select_sequences() function, assign to it in confirm_selection(), and then return it at the end of select_sequences().

The select_sequences() function never returns selected_sequences. So you need to have the select_sequences function return selected_sequences. If you add that after root.mainloop(), it should return the value as expected.
